# ASP:Label, span and javascript elementbyId access

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, getelementbyid

I am currently trying to access a  control that is within a  class.

HTML Code:

```
   <span class="GeoPanelHeaderLeft">
       <asp:Literal ID="LiteralHeaderText" runat="server" Text="New Survey Ticket"></asp:Literal>
     &nbsp
      &nbsp
      &nbsp
       <asp:Image ID = "errorImg" runat = "server" ImageUrl="..\Images\caution_red.gif" visible        = "false"/>
     <asp:Label ID = "literalerrortext2" runat="server" ClientIDMode= "Static"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID = "literalerrortext3" runat="server" ClientIDMode= "Static"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID = "LiteralErrorText" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
   function setError(message) {
            var test = window.document.getElementById("LiteralErrorText");
            var test2 = window.document.getElementById("literalerrortext2");
                var test3 = window.document.getElementById("literalerrortext3");


      }
```

When I run my javascript function, the getElementById function returns objects for
"literalerrortext2" and "literalerrortext3", however the object is null when it comes to
"LiteralErrorText".

I am using master pages and not sure why this is happening. If anyone can help with this that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have another control in your master page named "LiteralErrorText"? You can always emit the client id using `var test3 = document.getElementById("<%= LiteralErrorText.ClientID %>");`

Answer (score 2):

Your Literal control is rendered *literally* as **New Survey Ticket** (no html unless you choose to put it there)... unlike your Label controls which are rendered as `<span id=myid>Some text</span>`.